# Option to report a profile?

Tags: feature-request

As much fun as it would be to burn a few points downvoting spammers like [Los Angeles Criminal Lawyer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1986/los-angeles-criminal-lawyer), [Atlanta Data Center](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/2797/atlanta-data-center), and [Refrigerators](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1932/refrigerators) on the [Bulletin board software with voting capability for each post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/bulletin-board-software-with-voting-capability-for-each-post) thread, seems like it'd be just as productive to have the option to flag a user profile as obvious spam (whether or not the profile is associated with new posts).

Running a few popular vBulletin forums, I've seen spammers register just to have a profile with a link back to their site in it (many never bothered posting) so it would only make sense to add a Flag *Profile* option.

**Edit**

Closed per re-post at [StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68917/feature-request-flag-profile-closed) (apparently the accepted solution is to contact a mod or post on meta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we should definitely have this. Having mechanisms in place to keep spammers out is vital to maintaining the quality of a site, and especially an online community.

There also needs to be a quicker/more effective spam response system in place. I've flagged some obvious spam posts by different dummy accounts, and 8 hours later the posts are still there.

Comment: In the case of the linked post RE: Bulletin board software, the "Los Angeles Criminal Lawyer" spam has been up for more than two months...

Comment: Reporting a profile won't get action done any faster as it would be using the same notification system as reporting answers.